# What is the recommended approach to setup Sitecore 8.1 in Azure VM?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am new to Sitecore administration. I wanted to setup Sitecore 8.1 in an Azure vm. I have one Azure sql vm and one vm for Sitecore. So I would like to know the best recommended approach to set up Sitecore

1. using Sitecore web installer
2. from sitecore zip
3. using pre defined powershell script (not very much sure about steps)
4. SIM

Please guide me as I am new to Sitecore administration.

Comment: Big part of the work is how to deal with the config file, there are multiple very goed approaches but it is Opinion based. I think so

Answer (score 1):

Deb,

I know isn't the version that you were looking for, however you can get the idea in deal with a Sitecore installation and all its prerequistes. Please have a look here: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/installation_guide_sc70-a4.pdf

Based on Sitecore installation guide, I haven't seen a recommendation from them saying "install using EXE" or "install using ZIP". Actually, they show you both! Personally, I would suggest you to go through using ZIP.

Cheers,
Vinicius

Comment: sure. thank you . Is there any other alternative ? I have seen people using some scripts and they run it to install and that script will do everything like downloading necessary software if required ,I am not pretty much sure about this .

Comment: Deb,
I'm assuming you are asking about other ways to install Sitecore other than EXE and ZIP, and the answer is YES! And you will find plenty of them using PowerShell, however I am not sure if already exists a script that download necessary software, check requirements, and etc.
Also, you might get yourself creating some scripts in order to automate your own installations, deployments and so on!
Cheers, Vinicius